# Can you use Empowered Spell to reroll the healing dice for the Cure Wounds spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, healing, metamagic

Can the sorcerer's Empowered Spell metamagic option be used to reroll the healing dice for the *cure wounds* spell (or, for that matter, any healing spell)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope.

Empowered Spell specifically states:

> When you roll **damage** for a spell...

Healing is not damage so empowering spell doesn't apply to healing spells.

The [divine soul sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#DivineSoul)'s 6th-level Empowered Healing feature from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, however, *does* allow you to reroll healing dice. As covered on page 50:

> #### Empowered Healing
>
> Whenever you or an ally within 5 feet of you rolls dice to determine the
> number of hit points a spell restores, you can spend 1 sorcery point to reroll any number of those dice once, provided you aren't incapacitated.

Comment: So noted.  Guess I'll just ask my DM about houseruling it, then.

Comment: @Stackstuck make sure they understand that there are rules for this before they houserule it. some dm's may get upset if they think you've purposefully tried to bend the rules to make your character more powerful.

Comment: Oh, no, we're already doing that.  Whole reason I even asked this question is because in addition to my 20 sorcerer levels, I'm getting 4 in bard.

Comment: Back in the day, divine healing on the undead did damage right? That still the case in 5e? And if so, would Empowered Spell be applicable there?

Comment: Sadly, it is not, anymore.  Well, maybe with channel divinity, but I don't have that.

Comment: So for 5e,  Cure Wounds is no longer divine in nature?

Comment: @flaZer: Being "divine" in nature has no special meaning in 5e, as far as I know. There's no mechanical definition or distinction, that is. Healing spells don't affect undead any differently unless either the spell or the target has a trait that says otherwise.